# Reliable approach for loading resources in Java / JNLP

Tags: java, resources, jar, packaging, jnlp

I'm writing a Java application that needs to access several resources in a .jar file that is run over JNLP.

While the application works fine in my development environment (Eclipse) it doesn't work when executed through JNLP, apparently because it can't find the resource file in the jar. I've checked the resource file and the resources are most definitely there.

I'm currently using code like:

```
 someclass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/somefile.png");
```

What is the correct way to access a resource file in a .jar that will work with JNLP?

Comment: p.s. It also works as an executable jar run from the command line.... so it does seem to be a JNLP specific problem

Comment: Try using the context class loader: `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/somefile.png")`.

Comment: Looks promising (although for some reason I have to remove the leading "/" in the path). Just testing right now....

Comment: When you get a resource via a Class, the path is resolved relative to the class, unless you start it with a '/'. When you get it via a ClassLoader, it is always resolved as an absolute path and must not begin with a '/'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use : this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(name)
example: myClass.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/somefile.png")

two tips:
1 - use your own class that is in jar file. if used another class - for example Object - fails
2 - name i.e. resource must be without leading '/'

Comment: Thanks Romain! This seems to work, I think the problem was using a Java class that wasn't in my jar file

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck for a while on a similar issue and the comment from @Devon_C_Miller saved me (once I saw it, after some time!), so I thought I'd recopy it here:

> When you get a resource via a Class, the path is resolved relative to the class, unless you start it with a '/'. When you get it via a ClassLoader, it is always resolved as an absolute path and must not begin with a '/'.

In my case, I use the following syntax, for a file located in the JAR: `/properties/config.properties`:

```
//NO LEADING `/` EVEN IF IT IS AN ABSOLUTE PATH
private final static String CONFIG_FILE = "properties/config.properties";
InputStream resource = Configuration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(CONFIG_FILE);
```